# Wrap definition list text around image (CSS\HTML)

Tags: html, css

Having a problem trying to wrap text around an image in HTML with CSS. The context here is it's for a fiction series, and each character has his/her own term/definition pair for things like name, occupation, etc. that I fit into a <dl> list. This information should wrap around a single image in the upper-right corner of each character's info block. The <dl> list has a class called `categories` with the following CSS code:

```
dl.categories { overflow: hidden; padding: 0 5px 0 5px; }
dl.categories dt { float: left; font-weight: bold; color: #AAA; width: 200px; }
dl.categories dd { float: left; width: calc(100% - 200px); margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; }
dl.categories dt:after { content: " :: "; }
```

The image/span in question has the following CSS:

```
.floatright { float: right; clear: left; }
.featureimage { width: 200px; margin-right: 5px; border-radius: 15px; border: 2px solid black; }
```

Meanwhile, the code I have for my <dl> list is as follows:

```
<div class="bulletin post" id ="character1">
    <img src="images/characters/aaron.jpg" class="floatright featureimage" alt="" />
    <dl class="categories">
        <dt>Name</dt>
            <dd>Aaron</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

This is obviously ultra-condensed for brevity's sake. You'll notice the <img> element sitting just above the <dl>. What I'd like is for this image to float in the upper-right corner of the information in the <dl>, and for the information to wrap around the image as such:

[image: example of text wrapping around definition list]

So far, I have the image floating to the right successfully, but the text doesn't wrap around it. It just stops at the left border of the image, even if it's clear of the image vertically, leaving a gap on the right the same width as the image.

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? Am I using the wrong element (<span>)? Should the image be an element inside the definition list, like for example <dt style="display: none;">Image</dt><dd><img /></dd>? is there a CSS attribute I'm missing, or one I have that I shouldn't? I've tried a few things, but with mixed/disastrous results, and have tried a few solutions I've found around the web, but none quite gave me what I need.

The page this is appearing on is http://www.inagalaxyfarfarawry.com/characters.php.

Thanks!

Comment: What purpose does the span fill?

Comment: Actually, funny enough (or not), I can't remember now. I wrote the code long ago and it probably morphed and I didn't realize I didn't need it. I got rid of it and added the floatright class right into the <img> tag. I'll edit the code above to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

If you set

`text-align: justify;`

on the `<DL>` tag (or the `<DD>` tag) that will make it conform to the image.